# how to resize my flutter app according to every screen size?

Tags: flutter, dart, size

Im trying to create a page to convert Weight but the screen size from the Android emulator
and my phone are different,so how can i adjust my screen size for every ocasion?I tried to use Media Query but i don't know how exactly it works and I left it,idk if I need to use Media Query or something else...its my first project :<

The Android emulator

[image: The Android emulator]

and my phone

[image: and my phone]

The Widget

```
class Weight extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _WeightState createState() => _WeightState();
      }

class _WeightState extends State<Weight> {
 bool value = true;
 List<String> x = ["Pounds", "Kilograms", "Centrigrams"];
 List<bool> y = [false, false, false];
 String temp = "";
 var userQuestion = '';
 var userAnswer = '';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(50, 70, 205, 1),
      title: const Text('Weight and Mass'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3),
          height: 50,
          child: LiteRollingSwitch(
            //initial value
            value: true,
            textOn: 'Light',
            textOff: 'Night',
            colorOn: Colors.yellow[600],
            colorOff: Colors.grey[900],
            iconOn: Icons.wb_sunny,
            iconOff: Icons.brightness_3,
            textSize: 20.0,
            onChanged: (bool state) {
              value = state;
              print('Current State of SWITCH IS: $state');
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          
          child: buildMenuItem(
            text: x[0],
            icon: Icons.arrow_drop_down,
            onPressed: () {
              y[0] = true;
              openBottomSheet(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white70,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.deepPurple[900], width: 3.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(userQuestion,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 22)),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: buildMenuItem(
            text: x[1],
            icon: Icons.arrow_drop_down,
            onPressed: () {
              y[1] = true;
              openBottomSheet(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white70,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.deepPurple[900], width: 3.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(userAnswer,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 23)),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 75,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion = '';
                            userAnswer = '';
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.green,
                      buttonText: "C",
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion = userQuestion.substring(
                                0, userQuestion.length - 1);
                            if (userQuestion.length >= 1) {
                              converter();
                            } else {
                              userAnswer = '';
                            }
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.red,
                      buttonText: "⌫",
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 500,
                height: 75,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '7';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "7",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '8';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "8",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '9';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "9",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 500,
                height: 75,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '4';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "4",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '5';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "5",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '6';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "6",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 500,
                height: 75,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '1';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "1",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '2';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "2",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '3';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "3",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 75,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '0';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      buttonText: "0",
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                    MyButton(
                      buttonTapped: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            userQuestion += '.';
                            converter();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      color: Colors.white,
                      textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                      buttonText: ".",
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Have you considered to use [Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) package?

Comment: i don't have the version required,but probably I will change that

Answer (score 2):

you can call :

```
double sizeHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double sizeWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

example :

```
return Container(
         height : sizeHeight * 0.5,
         width : sizeWidth * 0.5
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a class to retrieve the sizes:

```
class SizexGet {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenwidth;
  static double screenheight;
  static double defaultsize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenheight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    screenwidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

double getProportionHieght(double inputhieght) {
  double screeHights = SizexGet.screenheight;
  return (inputhieght / 812.0) * screeHights;
}

double getProportionWidth(double inputwidth) {
  double screenwidths = SizexGet.screenwidth;
  return (inputwidth / 375.0) * screenwidths;
}
```

You can use the class as the following:

```
class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizexGet().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backColorPrimary,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: getProportionHieght(200),
                  width: getProportionWidth(200),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now the Widget will resize automatically when it is in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

you just wrap the whole body with **SingleChildScrollView** as I did in below code.
Actually this is not good practice but your all containers are hardcoded **height** and **width** so in this situation, you need **SingleChildScrollView**

```
class _WeightState extends State<Weight> {
  bool value = true;
  List<String> x = ["Pounds", "Kilograms", "Centrigrams"];
  List<bool> y = [false, false, false];
  String temp = "";
  var userQuestion = '';
  var userAnswer = '';
 var _width,_height;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    _height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(50, 70, 205, 1),
          title: const Text('Weight and Mass'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3),
              height: 50,
              child: LiteRollingSwitch(
                //initial value
                value: true,
                textOn: 'Light',
                textOff: 'Night',
                colorOn: Colors.yellow[600],
                colorOff: Colors.grey[900],
                iconOn: Icons.wb_sunny,
                iconOff: Icons.brightness_3,
                textSize: 20.0,
                onChanged: (bool state) {
                  value = state;
                  print('Current State of SWITCH IS: $state');
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: _height-AppBarTheme.of(context).toolbarHeight,
          width: _width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child:
                    buildMenuItem(
                      text: x[0],
                      icon: Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                      onPressed: () {
                        y[0] = true;
                        // openBottomSheet(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      border: Border.all(
                          color:
                          Colors.deepPurple[900],
                          width: 3.0),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(userQuestion,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 22)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: buildMenuItem(
                      text: x[1],
                      icon: Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                      onPressed: () {
                        y[1] = true;
                        openBottomSheet(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.deepPurple[900], width: 3.0),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(userAnswer,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 23)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 300,
                          height: 75,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion = '';
                                      userAnswer = '';
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.green,
                                buttonText: "C",
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion = userQuestion.substring(
                                          0, userQuestion.length - 1);
                                      if (userQuestion.length >= 1) {
                                        converter();
                                      } else {
                                        userAnswer = '';
                                      }
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.red,
                                buttonText: "⌫",
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 500,
                          height: 75,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '7';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "7",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '8';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "8",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '9';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "9",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 500,
                          height: 75,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '4';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "4",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '5';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "5",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '6';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "6",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 500,
                          height: 75,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '1';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "1",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '2';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "2",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '3';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "3",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 300,
                          height: 75,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '0';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                buttonText: "0",
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                              ),
                              MyButton(
                                buttonTapped: () {
                                  setState(
                                    () {
                                      userQuestion += '.';
                                      converter();
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                color: Colors.white,
                                textColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                                buttonText: ".",
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: well yeah with the SingleChildScrollView it's a bad practice because I just make the screen scrollable,I have hard code the height and  width from the containers so i can make them fit(to my phone screen)so I assume that i won't find any smaller screens(which is a bad practice too),but if I removed the hard code can I somehow make the screen resize according to a device?

Comment: If you need any help I will update my answer.

Comment: Well if you know how I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaQuery and minus the rest from it.

```
double screenHeight = 0.0;
double screenWidth = 0.0;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 // To Get AppBar Preferred Size
 AppBar appBar = AppBar(
 title: const Text("Screen new"),
 elevation: 0,
);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - // Total screen height
    appBar.preferredSize.height -  // Reducing Appbar height
    MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top; // This is the top status bar 
screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; // Total screen width

return SafeArea(  // To remove overlap with status bar on top
 child Scaffold(
   appBar: appBar, 
   body: Container(
   //If need to reduce height use screenHeight * 0.2 (* 1.0 is the full height)
          height: screenHeight, 
          width: screenWidth,
    child: ...... Add rest of the code Here ....
   )
  )
 );}
```